# How to use the result of select_tag to set link_to args

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what seems like a straight forward problem, I want to be able to change arguments on a link_to to something the user picks.  My app does not require a login so the usual methods of setting user prefs on login arn't appropriate.  The user selects an option from a select_tag like so (I'm using Haml);

```
 = select_tag('bible_version', options_for_select(['NIV','ESV', 'MSG'], :selected => @bible_version))
```

Here is part of my index view with the link_to;

```
  - @verses.each do |verse|
    %tr
      %td= verse.gospel_verse
      %td= link_to 'Read', 'http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=' + verse.gospel_verse + '&version=' + @bible_version
```

What would be the best way to change the @bible_version variable to the value the user chose and reset all the links?  I figure I need to set a cookie and dont mind doing a page refresh or using Javascript, but I cant get my brain around a clean way to do this.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test the below code, but seems like it would work in your on load function.

```
$("#bible_version").change(function(){
   $(your_links).attr("href") = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah,  Your suggestion would probably work, but I've decided it would be easier to parse the links in a controller action using Ruby (which I'm better at) than Javascript.